# SparkSQL: Ignore/convert rows with invalid date format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with column name 'date1' (timestamp (nullable = true)), formated like this

```
scala> sql("select date1 from tablename).show(20);
+-------------------+
|        date1      |
+-------------------+
|2016-08-20 00:00:00|
|2016-08-31 00:00:00|
|2016-08-31 00:00:00|
|2016-09-09 00:00:00|
|2016-09-08 00:00:00|
```

While reading through complete hive table, I am getting following error:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2633.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7206, ip-10-0-0-241.ec2.internal, executor 11): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 80 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 80.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 8944, ip-10-0-0-241.ec2.internal, executor 42): java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0000-12-30T00:00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
.....
.....
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0000-12-30T00:00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
```

How can I ignore/convert the records so that I am able to read table?

SparkVersion: 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

This is a source data issue. Try to read whole data for this column alone & write it

```
scala> sql("select date1 from tablename).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("path/to/file.parquet")
```

If this is the issue with this column, then you will get error.

You try to query the source data using '0000-12-30T00:00:00'

This is clearly a data issue that you need to identify and remove it.

You can try below query to ignore the rows

```
sql("select date1 from tablename where date1 <> '0000-12-30T00:00:00'").count
```

Comment: I made sure that it is data issue by running query: sql("select distinct(date1) from tablename").count. And i am getting exception in this only. So it is data issue only. My question is how to handle to such issue. There are only 4  such rows in million row and I want to ignore those rows altogether.

Comment: Edited my answer, you can try where clause. Just to make sure it doesn't raise issues , read the column as string, eliminate them & then cast it as date

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

spark.sql("""select cast(regexp_replace(date1,'[T,Z]',' ') as timestamp) from tablename""").show()

This will replace T/Z with a ' '(space) when it finds, otherwise it does nothing.

Hope this helps!